# Constraining a nested 3rd level relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm building an api using eager loading so i can simply return the user model with its deep relations and it automatically be converted as json. Here's the set up.

```
users
    id
    ..

clients
    id
    ..

user_clients
    id
    user_id
    client_id
    ..

campaigns
    id
    ..

client_campaigns
    id
    client_id
    campaign_id
    ..

campaign_activities
    id
    campaign_id
    ..

client_campaign_activity_templates
    id
    campaign_activity_id
    client_id *(templates are unique per client)*
    ..
```

I've setup the models' relationships.

```
User
    public function clients() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client','user_clients');
    }

Client
    public function campaigns() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Campaign','client_campaigns');
    }

Campaign
    public function activities() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CampaignActivity');
    }

CampaignActivity
    public function templates() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ClientCampaignActivityTemplate')
    }
```

I have a simple api endpoint to provide a JSON of a User object including its deep relations using eager loading.

```
public function getLoggedInUser(Request $request) {
    return \App\User::with('clients.campaigns.activities.templates')->find($request->user()->id);
}
```

Testing this using postman, I can get the user including its deep relations.

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "user1",
        "clients": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "client1",
                "campaigns": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "campaign1",
                        "activities": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "activity1",
                                "templates": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 1,
                                        "name": "template1 for client1",
                                        "client_id": 1,
                                        "body": "this is a template.",
                                    }, {
                                        "id": 2,
                                        "name": "template1 for client2",
                                        "client_id": 2,
                                        "body": "This is a template for client2"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }, {
                                "id": 2,
                                "name": "activity2",
                                "templates": []
                            }, {
                                "id": 3,
                                "name": "activity3",
                                "templates": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However, on the `user->clients->campaigns->activities->templates` level, it will list all the templates for that activity. I know based on the code of the relationships of the models above that it's supposed to behave like that.

So the question is **How would you filter the templates to filter for both campaign_activity_id and client_id?**

I've been experimenting on how to filter the templates so it will only list templates for that activity AND for that client as well. I have a working solution but it's N+1, I'd prefer eloquent approach if possible. I've been scouring with other questions, answers and comments for a closely similar problem, but I had no luck, hence I'm posting this one and seek for your thoughts. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my working solution, but I'm still interested if you guys have a better approach of doing this.

On the `CampaignActivity` model, I added a public property `client_id` and modified the relationship code to

```
CampaignActivity

    public $client_id = 0

    public function templates() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ClientCampaignActivityTemplate')->where('client_id', $this->client_id);
    }
```

and on my controller, limit the eager loading to activities only (actually, there are more sqls executed using eager loading[9] in this case vs just iterating[7], and also eager loading doesn't make sense anymore because we're iterating lol)

```
public function getLoggedInUser(Request $request) {
    foreach ($user->clients as $client)
        foreach( $client->campaigns as $campaign)
            foreach ($campaign->activities as $activity) {
                $activity->client_id = $client->id;
                $activity->templates; //to load the values
            }
    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need are [eager loading constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

```
public function getLoggedInUser(Request $request) {
    return \App\User::with('clients.campaigns.activities.templates',
        function($query) use($request) {
            $client_ids = Client::whereHas('users', function($q) use($request){
                $q->where('id', $request->user()->id);
            })->pluck('id');
            $query->whereIn('templates.client_id', $client_ids);
        })->find($request->user()->id);
}
```

Not tested but it should only require one additional query.

What I am doing is: define a constraint for your eager loading, namely only show those templates that have a `client_id` that is in the list (`pluck`) of Client IDs with a relation to the User.

Comment: thanks matthias, i guess i need to clarify my problem a bit more. but what happens with your code is it basically narrows the templates down by ALSO  checking if the template belongs to the clients, that belongs to the user. as a result, if user1 owns client1 and client2, activity1 will list under its templates `template1 for client1` and `template1 for client2`. i'm starting to think eager loading it to templates level isn't the right approach for my problem, as the templates looks to require to be iterated per client to achieve the result.

Comment: `template1 for client2` should not be included under the templates for `activity1` under `client1`, but should be in templates for `activity1` under `client2` :) i hope it gives a little more picture

Answer (score 0):

Try using closures to filter through related models:

```
$users = App\User::with([

'clients' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', $id);
},

'clients.campaigns' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', $id);
}

])->get();
```

Comment: Instead of *just* posting code, you may want to explain a little bit, or risk your post to be deleted.